# jpcap error sending packets cooked mode

Tags: java, c, pcap

I want to send a UDP packet using jpcap.

My code is:

```
    PcapNetworkInterface nif = Pcaps.getDevByName(args[0]); 
    int snapLen = 65536;
    PromiscuousMode mode = PromiscuousMode.NONPROMISCUOUS;
    int timeout = 10000;
    PcapHandle handle = nif.openLive(snapLen, mode, timeout);

    UdpPort srcPort = new UdpPort((short)1002,"");
    UdpPort dstPort = new UdpPort((short)2001, "");;
    short length = (short)12; 
    short checksum = (short)0xABCD; 



    UnknownPacket.Builder unknownb = new UnknownPacket.Builder(); 
    unknownb.rawData(new byte[] { (byte)0, (byte)1, (byte)2, (byte)3 }); 

    UdpPacket.Builder b = new UdpPacket.Builder(); 
    b.dstPort(dstPort) 
     .srcPort(srcPort) 
     .length(length) 
     .checksum(checksum) 
     .correctChecksumAtBuild(false) 
     .correctLengthAtBuild(false) 
     .payloadBuilder(unknownb); 

    EthernetPacket.Builder etherBuilder = new EthernetPacket.Builder();
    etherBuilder.dstAddr(MacAddress.getByName("FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF"))
                .srcAddr(MacAddress.getByName("FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF"))
                .type( EtherType.IPV4) // 
                .payloadBuilder(b) 
                .paddingAtBuild(true);


    Packet p = etherBuilder.build(); 


    int i=1;
    while(true) {

        handle.sendPacket(p); 
        System.out.println("send "+i);i++;
        try { 
          Thread.sleep(1000); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { 

        } 
    }
```

**After executing that ,i get :**

*org.pcap4j.core.PcapNativeException: Error occured in pcap_sendpacket(): 
Sending packets isn't supported in cooked mode
 at org.pcap4j.core.PcapHandle.sendPacket(PcapHandle.java:1242)
 at org.pcap4j.core.PcapHandle.sendPacket(PcapHandle.java:1212)*

And this is the link to c implementation:

https://github.com/frgtn/rpcapd-linux/blob/master/libpcap/pcap-linux.c#L1091

Answer (score 1):

I am definitely late to answer but I hope this code helps other people.

```
import org.pcap4j.core.PcapHandle;
import org.pcap4j.core.PcapNetworkInterface;
import org.pcap4j.packet.*;
import org.pcap4j.packet.namednumber.EtherType;
import org.pcap4j.packet.namednumber.IpNumber;
import org.pcap4j.packet.namednumber.IpVersion;
import org.pcap4j.packet.namednumber.UdpPort;
import org.pcap4j.util.MacAddress;
import org.pcap4j.util.NifSelector;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Inet4Address;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class RAWUDP {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[] pck = "Meow".getBytes();

        UnknownPacket unknownPacket = UnknownPacket.newPacket(pck, 0, pck.length);

        UdpPacket udpPacket = new UdpPacket.Builder()
                .srcAddr(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.6"))
                .dstAddr(InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.6"))
                .srcPort(UdpPort.getInstance((short) 54163))
                .dstPort(UdpPort.getInstance((short) 9110))
                .correctLengthAtBuild(true)
                .correctChecksumAtBuild(true)
                .payloadBuilder(unknownPacket.getBuilder())
                .build();

        IpV4Packet.Builder ipV4Builder = new IpV4Packet.Builder();

        ipV4Builder.version(IpVersion.IPV4)
                .tos(IpV4Rfc791Tos.newInstance((byte) 0))
                .ttl((byte) 100)
                .protocol(IpNumber.UDP)
                .srcAddr((Inet4Address) InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.6"))
                .dstAddr((Inet4Address) InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.6"))
                .payloadBuilder(udpPacket.getBuilder())
                .correctChecksumAtBuild(true)
                .correctLengthAtBuild(true);


        PcapNetworkInterface nif;
        try {
            nif = new NifSelector().selectNetworkInterface();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        if (nif == null) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.println(nif.getName() + "(" + nif.getDescription() + ")");

        final PcapHandle handle4send = nif.openLive(65536, PcapNetworkInterface.PromiscuousMode.PROMISCUOUS, 10);

        EthernetPacket.Builder etherBuilder = new EthernetPacket.Builder();
        etherBuilder.dstAddr(MacAddress.getByName("00:A0:C9:14:C8:29", ":"))
                .srcAddr(MacAddress.getByName("00:A0:C9:14:C8:29", ":"))
                .type(EtherType.IPV4)
                .payloadBuilder(ipV4Builder.build().getBuilder())
                .paddingAtBuild(true);

        Packet p = etherBuilder.build();

        handle4send.sendPacket(p);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used  https://gist.github.com/austinmarton/1922600

or another interface that function with jpcap

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the device on which you're sending the packet is an argument to the program.

Make sure it's an Ethernet device, as you're constructing an Ethernet packet.  Note that the "any" device not only isn't an Ethernet device, it's not a device at all - it's really the "no device", meaning that it listens on all devices, but won't send on any devices.